# Nested JSON in causes new entity values in Edit Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am working on an edit form for my company and someone on my team decided to change the formatting of our API payload return without consulting the rest of the team and now we are playing catchup.
Originally this was our return:

```
    {
       "status": 1, 
       "name": "Tank",
       "dimensions": "2.0 x 22.5 x 4.0"
    }
```

This layout worked perfectly any the edit form was fully functional.  He recently nested the JSON into a data element giving a payload that looks similar to this:

```
    {
       "status": 1, 
       "data" : {
            "name": "Tank",
            "dimensions": "2.0 x 2.5 x 4.0"
       }
    }
```

The problem is, now my onChange events are no longer working and I can no longer update the text in the field, because rather than updating the value on the *name* element inside the the *data* element, it is creating a new element call *data.name* like this:

```
    {
       "status": 1, 
       "data" : {
            "name": "Tank",
            "dimensions": "2.0 x 2.5 x 4.0"
       }
       "data.name": "Tanks",
       "data.dimensions": "3.5 x 3.5 x 4.0"
    }
```

Here is My Form:

**Here is my Form:**

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);


// Fetch Values
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${detailsUrl + selectedRecord.id}`);
      setValues( res.data );
    } catch (error) {
      setValues( error.response.data );
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);


// Validate Form
    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
      const temp = { ...errors };
      if ('data.name' in fieldValues) { 
          if (!fieldValues?.data?.name) {
              temp.name = 'Equipment Name is required.';  }
          else {temp.name = ''; }
      }
      if ('data.dimensions' in fieldValues) {
        if (!fieldValues?.data?.dimensions) {
            temp.dimensions = 'Dimensions are required.';  }
        else {temp.dimensions = ''; }
      }
      setErrors({
          ...temp
      });
      if (fieldValues === values)
          { return Object.values(temp).every(x => x === ''); }
    };


// Handle Input Change
    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
             [name]: ( typeof value === 'string' ? (value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart() : value )
        });
        if (validateOnChange)
          { validate({ [name]: value }); }
    };

return
 <>
 {values.status !== 1 ? <DataError /> :
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <Controls.Input  
            type='text'
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            name='name'
            label='Equipment Name'
            value={values.data.name}
        /> 
        <Controls.Input  
            type='text'
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            name='dimensions'
            label='Equipment Dimensions'
            value={values.data.dimensions}
        />  
        <Button
            type='submit'
            text='Submit'
            onClick={handleSubmit}
         />
    </Form>
    }
    </>
  );
```

I have also tried changing the name prop in the component to `name=data.name` and `name=data.dimensions` but it still creates new values just called with `data.` at the beginning.

When I send the values back to the DB, they don't need to be nested inside a data element, so is there a way to take this payload an un-nesting is so I can access the elements without the *data.* at the beginning? That might help.

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Handle Input Change
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  setValues((prevValues) => ({
    ...prevValues,
    data: {
      ...prevValues.data,
      [name]: typeof value === 'string' ? (value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart() : value,
    },
  }));
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-lederberg-4gndct

Comment: This answer does solve the problem, but it doesn't actually explain to OP `what` the problem was. Could you elaborate so they can learn and not just copy paste your answer into their code?

Comment: @DewaunAyers I think this answer solves the problem and also here I think that I don't have to explain anything the code speaks for itself

Comment: The code may speak for itself to someone with experience, but you should consider that OP might not have that experience and quite possibly people reading this post might not either.